# Symfony2 - Show all tables from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I would like to retrieve all the tables of my database as a list.

i tried to do a "Show databases" on a query but as i'm not using a class I defined (entity) in symfony it's not working.

And with DQL :

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
   $query = $em->createQuery(
        'show databases');

    $result = $query->getResult();
```

This error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 0: Error: Expected SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE, got 'show'
```

Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have a couple cases where I need to use complex sql statements/functions that I just couldn't do in DQL. Luckily, Symfony2/doctrine provide a method to grab the current database connection and bypass doctrine entirely.

```
//get connection
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
//run a query
$users= $conn->fetchAll('select * from users');
```

Be **very** careful when using this method, however. Since you are bypassing doctrine, you need to handle any security concerns like SQL injection yourself.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in a different answer, you can use `Doctrine\DBAL` for that:

```
/** @type \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection */
$connection = ...;

/** @type \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySqlSchemaManager $sm */
$sm = $connection->getSchemaManager();
```

And then just list the tables as `Array`:

```
var_dump( $sm->listDatabases() );
```

Comment: You also can do ->listTableNames() to get all tabels

Comment: I get error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySqlSchemaManager.php on line 99

Comment: @vee how do you call it? Or is this further processing instead of a dump?

Comment: I found that I set fetch mode to `\PDO::FETCH_OBJ` but without set fetch mode, it return nothing.

Comment: @vee Your error is _not_ from the `var_dump()`, but from some action you are performing.

Comment: dont worry remove that fetch obj works fine because MySqlSchemaManager.ph‌​p on line 99 use array.

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents:

```
getContainer()->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection')->getSchemaManager()->listTableNames()
```

This will give you an array of table names.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question _show all tables from database_. Thanks.

Comment: At least with Doctrine `2.6+` you will **not** get table names, but instances of `Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table`. [Source](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.6/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.html#method_listTables) To get the name, simply use `getName()` on the table instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can add Doctrine DBAL to your project and it will give you the tools you need. You can list databases, tables from a database, columns from a table etc etc

More in Doctrine DBAL documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine is a ORM, it is not intended to list all the databases. Beside that, usually for the current user you don't have the right to show all databases in the server, this can prove to be a big security breach.

Basicly, doctrine does not know how to interpret your query, you have to use a native query for this: [Doctrine Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: Your link doesn't work anymore. For `2.6.6` you can use https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html . For `2.7` please use https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html